# Ubuntu20.04 access internet when connected to wifi of particular device, but not others

Tags: networking, internet, ubuntu-touch

<br**Hello everyone**
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. and Ubuntu can only access the internet with my Old phone, gionee s10. But with my new phone,gionee M12, Ubuntu can not access the internet. Even though Ubuntu have recognize the phone hotspot, and it is connected to the phone, but access to Internet on Ubuntu is a problem
Pls I need assistance

Comment: what happens if you usb-tether your ubuntu with your phone?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.